# Secured Logo (Eg: Verisign) in the Checkout

Tags: checkout

In the checkout portion of an eCommerce site, is it mandatory or legally required to have the "Secured Symbol" (Eg: Verisign Logo) be a click through link to related information? Or it can be a just static image?

Comment: There is no online web-standard of legality. In some territories it might be required. Likewise, some carriers could potentially require it. However, as far as I know, there's no "requirement" that the card images do anything.

Comment: This isn't a UX question - the requirements for any logos would be dependent upon the TOS of the vendor you're using (such as Verisign)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a requirement (I think the commenters are right that this isn't a user experience issue).  However, from a user interface point of view, I think a static image would be pretty useless.

The reason is obvious: it could be fake.  Anyone can put an image on their site.  The value of the VeriSign certificate is that you can go to *their* trusted site and see it.  If your site, unlike every other site out there, did not link to the actual certificate, it would look very suspicious.